# String removal in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, substring

New here and new to coding really. Any help would be great. I am sorry if I do not get the proper format of the forum or community. Also, my terminology for coding discussion may be off as well.

I would like to check to see if a substring pair exists and then remove the pair for multiple substrings. I have tried the following:

```
s = 'aabbccddee'

    for j in range(0,(len(s)-1)): 
        y = j + 1
        if s[j].lower() + s[y].lower() in ['aa','bb','cc','dd']:
            z =  s[j] + s[y]
            s = s.replace(z,'')
    else:
        print(False)
```

The desired output would be `s ='ee'` in this case. The best I have achieved is `'bbccddee'`

The range -1 was because I was getting an out of range error. This seemed to fix it.

And the `z` is there because `s.replace(s[j].lower() + s[y].lower(),"")` did not pass.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating it. You can simply call `s.replace('aa', '')` to remove "aa" from your string. You can loop over the elements of your target strings `['aa','bb', ...]` and call `s.replace()` for each one.

Comment: Thank you. I seems I got the logic backwards. Instead of checking if every possible substring macthes the targets, check if the targets exist in the string. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to remove some substrings from `s`, you can simply do this:

```
 targets = ['aa','bb','cc','dd']
 for t in targets:
      s = s.replace(t, '')
```

There is no need to manually check if the substring is actually there, because `replace` will do that anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I seems I got the logic backwards. Instead of checking if every possible substring macthes the targets, check if the targets exist in the string. Correct?

Comment: @stewman Yes, if your objective is to remove those substrings from `s`, a simple call to `replace` will do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a hint and hope you can proceed further.

After replacing 'aa' with '', when you go to second iteration it starts checking from second 'b' because the value of j is 1. As you are looping over and modifying the same string, the result is not what you expect.

Comment: Thank. So removal of string resets the index basically, but i does not change? Removal of aa = s[01] then s = [bbccddee] = [012345678], but i has increased. Correct?

Comment: No, J has actually moved to 1, but as the string is modified so next substring you will be checking is s[1, 2] which will be 'bc' not 'bb' which was expected from us. As the program did not find bc in list, it could not replace.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and the help in general.